# Publishing Website in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web, publish

i am trying to publish my first website so i can move it to another server location where the code can't be manipulated (Customer own Server).

the problem is all the javascript functions aren't working any more!
i think the reason is because the website is reading from the DLLS and not from the sourcecode itself!

what can i do to make sure that the website can see the js files

thank you in advance!

Comment: Have your paths to your js files changed? Are you under a virtual directory on the server? JS files aren't located in DLLs (they have nothing to do with server-side code), they need to be on the server's filesystem so browsers can access them. Is your browser throwing an error?

Comment: Thanks Chris, but i have double checked the the files are there, and from my ASPx pages i have the following code
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script>

Comment: I think your script source address is not valid and browser can't load them. Check if this JS files are readeable by other users - so if they are not located in private (locked) folder. Try to open this files directly from browser, like www.youraddress.com/locationoffile.js if the file open normally then the script src address is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check the developer tools in your web browser for error messages. How you do this will depend on the browser you are using. You have likely got some errors in the paths to your javascript files. This would show up as missing files in you console.